# Do Begin/End async socket methods (APM) exists on .net standard?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard

I've been playing around with net standard sockets for a couple of days and didn't found any begin/end method on the Socket class, only the *Async methods which uses SocketAsyncEventArgs (which is overkill for a client scenario).

Is there any plan of Begin/End methods being added on a near future?

Comment: Can you name a specific method you're looking for that doesn't have a Begin/End version?  They exist and use IAsync which is...standard .NET stuff for async operations.  The named "*Async" methods are...yeah, probably overkill for a client.

Comment: BeginConnect, EndConnect and so on...

I'm using NETStandard.Library (1.6.1) and the Socket class from System.Net.Sockets (4.3.0) miss all of those methods.

Comment: Crap.  Sorry, I missed the implied upper casing of "Standard" and just thought you meant "normal" :)  (As in not Compact Framework or something).  The Begin/End stuff is older (and less efficient) than Async so I doubt it'll get added if it hasn't been already.

Comment: I haven't been using .NET Core, and don't know specifically, but if you don't see the methods there, it doesn't seem likely they exist. You've have to screw up pretty badly to get a `Socket` class defined in your project but have it be something other than the .NET class. Assuming .NET Standard supports `NetworkStream`, the best approach is to wrap your socket in a stream and use the async methods on `Stream`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These methods have been added to .NET Standard 2.0 and are not available on .NET Standard <= 1.6. The async variants of these methods however are available but the Begin/End variants have been added to 2.0 for compatibility with legacy code.

You can check the availability of methods on https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginAccept(AsyncCallback,Object)